# Get branch commits in a Github action

Tags: continuous-integration, pull-request, github-actions

Given a Github Action for a pull request, I would like to get the list of all the commits in that PR / branch. I can do `git log master..` but it fails in the Action:

```
steps: 
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    with:
      ref: ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }}
      fetch-depth: 0
  - run: git log ${{ github.event.pull_request.base.ref }}..
```

> fatal: bad revision 'master'

Any hint why that fails?

Comment: It might be failing due to checkout being shallow by default. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62293647/11934042).

Comment: @peterevans thanks for the hint. I've added it to [your answer to that other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62334460/git-history-in-a-github-action). Still it continues failing with the same error for that script.

Answer (score 1):

This action misses a `git fetch`. The other branches can then be accessed with the `origin/` prefix.

```
steps: 
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    with:
      ref: ${{ github.event.pull_request.head.sha }}
      fetch-depth: 0
  - run: git fetch
  - run: git log origin/${{ github.event.pull_request.base.ref }}..
```